# Printing a success message if no errors have yet been thrown in the current session

Tags: warning-messages, error-tracking, error-trapping

I plan to run a lengthy Mathematica script on a Linux terminal (by "a Linux terminal," I mean that I have text output only -- no GUI), using the program `math`.  To be able to track the execution progress of my script, I would like to `Print` "success messages" to the terminal when no errors or warnings have been thrown by Mathematica in the current session.

For example, here is a very basic script that `Import`s two text files, `test1.txt` and `test2.txt`, using the `"Table"` specification.  I would like to write a function or expression that sets the variable `success` to `True` when no error or warning messages have yet been thrown by Mathematica.

```
Import["test1.txt", "Table"]
success = f;
If[success, Print["test1.txt import successful!"];, Print["General failuire!"];];

Import["test2.txt", "Table"]
success = f;
If[success, Print["test2.txt import successful!"];, Print["General failure!"];];
```

where `f` is a function or expression that evaluates to `True` when *no error or warning messages have yet been thrown by Mathematica*.

Please note that I am *not* trying to write a function or expression `f` that determines if `test1.txt` or `test2.txt` exists.  Rather, I am trying to write an `f` that determines whether **any** errors or warnings **at all** have been thrown during the current Mathematica session.  If any have been thrown prior to when `f` is called, then `success` should *always* be set to `False`, for the remainder of the Mathematica session.

Do you have any advice on this?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you look for is the function `Check` which will give you the possibility to implement what you ask for in several variants, the most simple probably be this:

```
success=Check[Import["test1.txt", "Table"];True, False]
```

See the documentation of `Check` for more details...